# MPD drops icecast connection when stopping

Tags: audio, streaming, icecast, mpd

Since I have moved my streaming server on linux I have the following problem:
I am using MPD alongside with icecast and everytime MPD stops playing, the stream is closed.
This is a problem, because when I am changing from a playlist to a stream, MPD drops the connection with icecast and clients have to refresh.

To recreate:
1) Play a song with an MPD client
2) Stop the song
3) Play a song again

The connection to the stream is dropped and a new connection is started.

How can I keep the icecast connection open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use always_on yes in your shout audio so MPD will produce silence to output and will not close it. [From MPD docs:](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/html/user.html#configuring-audio-outputs)

> **always_on yes|no**
>   If set to yes, then **MPD** attempts to keep this audio output always open. This may be useful for streaming servers when you don't want to disconnect all listeners even when playback is accidentally stopped.